# Как с помощью telethon узнать забанен ли аккаунт?

Tags: python, telethon

появился вопрос как проверить забанен ли аккаунт c библиотекой telethon?

Answer (score 0):

При помощи исключения

```
this_client = TelegramClient(phone_number, api_id, api_hash)
        this_client.connect() 
        if not this_client.is_user_authorized():
            try:
                this_client.send_code_request(phone_number)
            except telethon.errors.rpc_error_list.PhoneNumberBannedError:
                print("Phone number is banned.")
                this_client.disconnect()
```

Comment: Он мне не выдает такое исключение, я так уже пробовал, он даже код запрашивает почему то хотя аккаунт сто процентов забанен

Comment: можете помочь?b

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66601313/list-of-removed-banned-users-in-a-telegram-group-channel-using-telethon
это пробовали ?